# Terraform/rancher2auth_config_github: Unauthorized 401: must authenticate

Tags: github, terraform, rancher

I'm trying to configure Github authentication for rancher2 following this link : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/rancher/rancher2/latest/docs/resources/auth_config_github

but when using this resource, I get 401 Unauthorized response.

here is my code :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    rancher2 = {
      source = "rancher/rancher2"
      version = "1.21.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "rancher2" {
  api_url   = "https://{{ rancher_public_domain }}"
  bootstrap = true
}

resource "rancher2_bootstrap" "admin" {
  password = "{{ admin_password }}"
  telemetry = false
  ui_default_landing = "ember"
}

resource "rancher2_auth_config_github" "github" {
  client_id = "<MY_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID>"
  client_secret = "<MY_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET>"
  enabled = true
}

output "rancher_username" {
  value = rancher2_bootstrap.admin.user
}

output "rancher_token" {
  value = rancher2_bootstrap.admin.token
  sensitive = true
}

output "rancher_url" {
  value = rancher2_bootstrap.admin.url
}
```

the error is :

```
Error: Bad response statusCode [401]. Status [401 Unauthorized]. Body: [message=Unauthorized 401: must authenticate] from [https://{{ rancher_public_domain }}]

  with rancher2_auth_config_github.github,
  on main.tf line 21, in resource "rancher2_auth_config_github" "github":
  21: resource "rancher2_auth_config_github" "github" {
```

the error doesn't occur when i'm not using this resource.
Can I have some help ? Thanks

Comment: Are you supplying credentials for the rancher provider?

Comment: just a password for the admin user with the resource "rancher2_bootstrap"

Answer (score 1):

According to the Rancher/RKE documentation for Github authentication, and the Rancher provider documentation, the `rancher2_auth_config_github` needs a provider with `admin` configuration, and not `bootstrap`. We can use the `rancher2_bootstrap` resource's exported resource attribute `token` to authenticate for this:

```
provider "rancher2" {
  api_url   = rancher2_bootstrap.admin.url
  token_key = rancher2_bootstrap.admin.token
}
```

The problem now is that this second provider configuration will conflict with the `bootstrap` provider configuration. We can use provider aliases for this:

```
provider "rancher2" {
  api_url   = rancher2_bootstrap.admin.url
  token_key = rancher2_bootstrap.admin.token
  alias     = "admin"
}

resource "rancher2_auth_config_github" "github" {
  provider = rancher2.admin

  client_id     = "<MY_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID>"
  client_secret = "<MY_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET>"
  enabled       = true
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer i'll give it a try and give you feedback